# gwtuploader change default response

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

Can I change default response in gwtuploader ? I know that I can add own message but I need change deafult becasue in some files have this error :

```
[INFO] incorrect response: C:\fakepath\Bez tytułu.jpg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<response>
<field>GWTMU-05262228029563762</field>
<name>BezÂ&nbsp;tytuĹ‚u.jpg</name>
<ctype>image/jpeg</ctype>
<finished>ok</finished>
<size>187373</size>
</response>
```

I need remove from "name" parameter this "&nbsp" becasue its stop upload.

Comment: Maybe if I can rewrite Utils.basename() method I can change this...